# How to integrate Data VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm currently trying to integrate data from one excel worksheet into another. CompanyName is the primary source key for sheet one and the PKEY for the other worksheet is Company_Name. I'm trying to write a macro that finds the company name in sheet two based on the company name in sheet 1. Then to copy the row from sheet one to the matching row in sheet two.

```
Sub Method1()

Dim PKEY As String
Dim CompanyName As Missed_Macro_Info.CompanyName
Dim Company_Name As Filtered_Suspect_Sheet.Company_Name
Set PKEY = Range("D2:D513")

CompanyName = Missed_Macro_Info1.company.FindByCompanyName("PKEY")

For a = PKEY To 1 Step -1

    If CompanyName.Value = Company_Name.Value Then
        Copy (CompanyName.Row)
        Paste (Company_Name.Row)
    Else
    End If


End Sub
```

I receive a "User-defined type not defined" Error at

```
Dim CompanyName As Missed_Macro_Info.CompanyName
```

If it would be easier to user Vlookup for this please let me know, I'm not to familiar with VBA.

Comment: When you define a variable with vim you specify its type, types can be built in into vba (string, integer, double) or they can be objects defined by plugins (ranges,workbooks, worksheets.) 
Missed_Macro_Info isn't a valid type.

Take a look at the built in types to get an idea of what "dim variable as type" means:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Very puzzled by your code.  When one writes `Dim foo as Lib1.Class1` then `Lib1` is the library and `Class1` is the class.   So one would write `Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet` to define a worksheet variable, here the Worksheet class resides in the `Excel` library.  One can add references to libraries in the Excel VBA IDE by going to the menu bar at the top of the windows and selecting Tools->References and then selecting from a list of libraries that also include other workbooks loaded.

I'd need to know more.  Do you have other workbooks open?  `Missed_Macro_Info` would need to be the VBA project name of one such opened workbook; as would `Filtered_Suspect_Sheet`.  One can rename a VBA project in the VBA IDE project explorer by clicking on the root node and then right-click to get context menu and select VBAProject properties to get a dialog window up.

Where did you get this code?

That such projects are not referenced is the cause of your compilation error.

Comment: I did my best to relate what I want to do with what I found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Could you show me a barebone way of scripting what I'm trying to do? I can't understand how to use the FindBy operator correctly

Comment: msdn reference is VB.Net, you have posted in VBA forum.